# symfony form : how to show the parameter in the view, "variable does not exist..."

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm using a form with 2 classes ("`ArticleType`" and "`ArticleHandler`") for my class Article.

I would like to send the id of the article I've just created, but I can't manage to show this id parameter in the view :

In the controller, I send my article's id :

```
$handler = new ArticleHandler($form, $request, $em);
if ($handler->process()){
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('myproject_show', array('id' => $article->getId())) );
}
```

and in the view, I've got an error with :

```
{% block body %}
    <p>the id :</p>
    {{ id }}
{% endblock %}
```

or `entity.id` (as in the CRUD) :

> Variable "id" does not exist...
>   Variable "entity.id" does not exist...

Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks

---

EDIT :
here's my method :

```
public function addAction()
{
    $article = new Article();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType(), $article);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $handler = new ArticleHandler($form, $request, $em);
    if ($handler->process()){
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('myproject_show', array('id' => $article->getId())) );
    }

    return $this->render('ProjBlogBundle:Blog:add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

and here's the view :

```
{% extends "ProjBlogBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}
  the title - {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block sousbody %}
    <p>here's the article i've just created :</p>
    {{ id }}
{% endblock %}
```

---

EDIT N°2 :

```
myproject_show:
    pattern:  /show/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: ProjBlogBundle:Blog:show, id:5 }
```

Comment: Did you pass your entity into the template?

Comment: @meze : sorry what do you mean?

Comment: You need to pass parameters into your template: `$this->render('Bundle::show', array('id' => $id))`. Show the code of action that `myproject_show` is configured to.

Comment: @meze : i passed the variable (getId) through the function : `('myproject_show', array('id' => $article->getId())) )` ? if you're talking about something else let me know : i edited my post above.

Comment: You showed your "Add" action, not "Show". `('myproject_show', array('id' => $article->getId())) )` here you pass id parameter in url, not in the view.

Comment: @meze : yeah i don't have a show action, i actually wrote "myproject_show" in the routing yml file (see the post above i've just edited) how should i do ?

Comment: @meze : i tried to create a `showAction`method, but i can't manage to call this method from addAction, i put this line : `return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ProjBlogBundle:Blog:show', array('id' => $article->getId())) );` but the path of my url is not recognized, do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you worked with symfony2 before? I recommend to read [this tutorial](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/).

Comment: @meze : no, i'm just beginning, thanks for the link, i'll read the tutorial with a lot of attention, but on this specific question, do you know what i should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a variable in a template you need to pass it when you render your template:

```
//ProjBlogBundle:Blog:show
public function showAction($id)
{
    return $this->render('ProjBlogBundle:Blog:show.html.twig', array(
        'id' => $id
    ));
}
```

`$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('myproject_show', array('id' => $article->getId())) );` returns only HTTP 302-response without rendering a template, and the browser is redirected to the generated url...